# Kernel and image of orthogonal projection

Tags: functional-analysis, orthogonality, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

> Let $X$ be a Hilbert space and $Y$ be a closed subspace, every vector $x \in X$ can be uniquely represented as  $x=y+z$, $y \in Y$, $z \in Y^\bot$. Then the map
> $$P_Y:X \to X, \quad P_Y(x)=y$$ is called the orthogonal projection in
> $X$ onto $Y$.

I need to prove that $\text{Im}(P_Y)=Y$ and $\ker(P_Y)=Y^\bot$.

As for the image: the result seems to follow straight forward from the definition: $$P_Y(x)=y \in Y \quad \forall x \in X \implies \text{Im}(P_Y)=Y.$$

Kernel: it seems to be obvious but it's hard to think of any proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the image you only proved one containment, namely ${\rm im}(P_Y)\subseteq Y$.
The other containment holds because $P_Y(y)=y$ for every $y\in Y$.

For the kernel, simply write the definitions: suppose an arbitrary $x\in X$ is given, decompose it as $x=y+z,\ y\in Y,\ z\in Y^\perp$, then
$$P_Y(x)=P_Y(y+z)=y$$
So it's $0$ iff $y=0$ iff $x=z$ iff $x\in Y^\perp$.